# How to display widgets on a frame that is mounted on canvas in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I created a main root with two frames.

-One frame is for program toolbar.

-Other frame is for canvas where data will be displayed and a scrollbar widget.

-Inside of the canvas is a third smaller frame which will be used for scrolling trough data.

However, when I try to define new widgets and place them on that third smaller frame, nothing happens. I'm defining new widgets inside of a function call of a button command. I have also tried declaring everything as global variables but without luck.

Hint: I tried placing the code from the function to the top level of the code and it works. Also, if I try to mount these widgets on the toolbar frame it also works. It seems that the only thing I can't do is to mount these new widgets on the small frame that is inside  the canvas.

I used a simple for loop to create labels just for testing.

Could anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk



#Creating main window
root = Tk()
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)



#Defining Background

toolbar = Frame(root, width=613, height=114)
toolbar.grid(row=0, column=0)

background_frame = Frame(root, width=615, height=560)
background_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

background = Canvas(background_frame, width=615, height=560)
background.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

scroll_bar = ttk.Scrollbar(background_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=background.yview)
scroll_bar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

background.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_bar.set)
background.bind('<Configure>', lambda e:background.configure(scrollregion = background.bbox('all')))

second_frame = Frame(background)
background.create_window(150,100, window=second_frame, anchor='nw')


def confirm1():
    
    
    for x in range(100): 
        Label(second_frame, text = x ).grid(row=x, column=1)




show_labels = Button(toolbar, text= "Show labels", fg="black", command=confirm1)
show_labels.grid(row=0, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

[Picture of the app so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNaA0.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function)

Comment: The link you provided is about the photos. I don't have a problem with that. Background image shows up fine. For some reason I' can't add labels or buttons to that frame when they are defined within a func. Also the scroll bar is not working. Maybe It's because  I'm using a lambda func at one point?? Now I'm just guessing...

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mre]. That means take out everything unrelated to the problem.

Comment: I think I have provided the minimal reproducible code. Thank you for your time. Click on the button "By store"

Comment: Does having an `iconbitmap` have anything to with the problem, as well as the eight image files? I think not.

Comment: Sorry, I see what you mean. I believe I have now removed everything that was redundant. Now when I press the button all the labels show on the background, but the scroll button is not working.

Comment: That's an improvement codewise (it's runnable), however I think it's changed so much that you also need to update the text describing what it is you want to know.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I have now changed the question as well. Maybe you can help me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I surely can't reproduce the issue with your current code, but looking at the previous edit it is pretty clear what your problem is.

<sub>(taken from your previous edit)</sub>

```py
def confirm1():
    
    global background_image1

    background.delete('all')  # <--- this line of code
 
    for x in range(100): 
        Label(second_frame, text = x ).grid(row=x, column=1)
```

Here you delete all your items from your canvas:

```py
background.delete('all')
```

hence no item appears.

You should instead delete only those items that you want to remove by passing the id or tags to `delete` method. You can delete multiple items together at once by giving the same tags.

Another option would be to recreate the frame item again on canvas using `create_window` (Do note: your frame is not deleted/destroyed, it's only removed from canvas)

Comment: Thank you! But now I have a second problem. I have edited the question to match the current problem.

Comment: @RastkoGojgic You should never change the existing question instead, you should ask a new one after rolling back on your edit.

Comment: Ok, should I delete this one then?

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I have now returned the previous edit, and will ask a new question separately.